# javascript variable inside string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain me why the variable `rectpos` inside the string wont work? It work for me  `'n' + variable;` in another snippet but why is this syntax wrong?

```
var allpositions = Array(0,cx*20,cx*40,cx*60,cx*80,cx*100);
  var rectpos =  allpositions[Math.floor(Math.random()*allpositions.length)];
box.style.cssText = "left:" + rectpos + ";position:absolute";
```

Comment: Looks like it should be `"left:" + rectpos + "px;position:absolute"`.

Comment: Oh thank you I'm so dumb. :D

Comment: Or even `box.style.left = rectpos + 'px'; box.style.position = ...` etc.

Comment: *"why is this syntax wrong"* If you don't get a syntax error, then it's not wrong. *"[...] inside the string wont work"* You need to elaborate on "not work".